# show there exists a subspace V of X such that $U \cap V = \{0\}$ and X = U + V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be a linear space and $U$ be a subspace of $X$. Show that there exists a subspace $V$ of $X$, such that $U \cap V = \{0\}$ and $X = U + V$.

I'm a little confused here, should we assume the latter two situations and try to show V is a subspace, or suppose V is a subspace and try to show the latter two situations.

Comment: The only thing you're assuming is that $U \leq X$. You have no assumptions on $V$ at all, so you have to first show that a subspace $V \leq X$ exists, satisfying $U \cap V = \{0\}$ **and** $X=U+V$ (equivalently $X=U \oplus V$). What happens if you take a basis of $U$ and extend it to a basis of $V$? Can you then use this basis to construct $V$?

Comment: Neither of the options you suggest are correct. I can't reword the problem in any other way, it seems clear to me. The best I can to is rewrite the question symbolically for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the finite dimensional case:

Choose some basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_k\}\;$ of $\;U\;$  and complete it to a basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_k, v_1,..,v_{n-k}\}\;$ of the whole space $\;X\;$. Now simply take $\;V:=Span\{v_1,...,v_{n-k}\}\;$.

In the infinite dimensional case: exactly as above but we may need AC (or what ammounts to the same in ZFC: the existence of a basis for *any* vector space).

Comment: Do we require choice for that though? The proposition at least *looks* much weaker than choice...

Comment: @fgp In the second case I think we do: the existence of a basis for *any* vector space is equivalent with AC in ZFC .